# Getting Data using JSON & AJAX in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby

How can I get data from database on entering/changing keywords (like on change command of textfield) usin JSON & AJAX in Ruby on Rails?
Please give me any tutorial or the code how to do this.

Comment: What else have you tried?

Comment: I have not used any ajax & json till now. I have just done saving or getting data from db in ruby on rails. But I want to get data on key change event of textbox in the view.

Comment: [what-have-you-tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @SaurabhJain : Thanks for that article that encouraged me. :)
I have done it by my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

[jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[respond_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#listing-all-posts)